# Tag for the new Final Fantasy XIII (Lightning Returns)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The official name of the game is `Lightning Returns: Final Fantasy XIII`.

I tried to create the tag [lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13) but it exceeds the 25 character length cap.

The actual tag being used (I think 3 questions now) is [lightning-returns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-returns), but I think we should add some way that it is a Final Fantasy.

What should it be the tag name? Maybe [lightning-returns-ff13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-returns-ff13)?

Comment: Rather, ff13-lightning-returns, or similar (tentatively applied); we prolly also need a synonym from final-fantasy-13-lr

Comment: I think lightning-returns is better than ff13-lightning-returns from a readability and simpler-is-better point of view... it's not like we need to disambiguate with another game titled lightning-returns, and it's unlikely with trademarks the way they are that we ever will need to.

Comment: I would've thought plain old "lightning-returns" is fine, we don't need to add any mention to "final fantasy XIII". After all, one of our most popular tags "skyrim" has no mention to "the elder scrolls 5".

Answer (score 5):

This tag was created as [ff13-lightning-returns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ff13-lightning-returns). However, now that the character limit was increased to 35, I don't see any reason why we shouldn't rename this.

We could use either [final-fantasy-13-lightning-returns](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-13-lightning-returns) or [lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13).

Comment: Would it be more prudent to use "Lightning Returns: Final Fantasy 13" as that is the official arrangement of the words? We can still add 'final-fantasy-13-lightning-returns' as a synonym.

Comment: @Robotnik updated my answer to suggest both names

Comment: @Robotnik After some thought, the official title is probably better. ([tag:lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13])

Comment: @Robotnik Now that there's a consensus for [lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13], would you be able to rename this tag?

Comment: @Thunderforge & Steve - the tag is now [tag:lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13], with the original ff tag and [tag:final-fantasy-13-lightning-returns] as synonyms

Answer (score -6):

I think it should be FF-XIII-LR. It is only 10 characters and it well suites the name.

Comment: Other than conforming with the 26 character limit, there is no advantage to shorter tags; such artificial concision is to be scorned and avoided, not encouraged and sought out.